# Problem with building Boost Graph Library Python bindings under Leopard

Tags: python, boost, graph, osx-leopard, binding

I've inherited some Python code which is importing boost.graph and I'm having an issue setting up the following under Mac OS X Leopard (I believe this is what I need to install to get it working):

http://osl.iu.edu/~dgregor/bgl-python/

According to the readme I need to build with bjam, but I see the following error:

```
[matt@imac ~/Downloads/bgl-python-0.9]$ bjam
error: Could not find parent for project at '.'
error: Did not find Jamfile or project-root.jam in any parent directory.
```

I'm running a full Macports stack of python25, boost, boost-jam, boost-build.

I don't have any experience with building using bjam. Can anyone offer any help?

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests the project is not a standalone, and is meant to be put inside the Boost source tree.